# React Native, Axios GET call throws [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]

Tags: django, react-native, docker

I am wiring up the backend and frontend of my application with React Native, using Docker with Django.

I am trying to fire a basic axios get call like this:

```
 Axios.get(`https://127.0.0.1:8000/products/inventory/1`)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })

    console.log(data)
  }, [])
```

I just want to get the data and get this wired up. The backend is running in a Docker container on http://127.0.0.1:8000/, but from the frontend I cannot reach this address, and axios is throwing an unhandled promise rejection.

Now, I don't know if I am missing some crucial passages but this would not work in any way.
If you need some additional info I can provide them to you.

Comment: How are you running the application, on port 8000, on the same host as the browser?  Can you reach the container from non-browser paths like `curl`?  ("Running on 127.0.0.1" often suggests a misconfiguration where the backend is unreachable from outside its container; the backend needs to listen on a special all-interfaces address 0.0.0.0, and the frontend code needs to name the host the container is running on.)

Comment: The application is running through expo on http://localhost:19002/, while the backend is running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/. 
What do you mean with 'the frontend code needs to name the host the container is running ok'? Thanks for your time meanwhile :)